# Does Rust have syntax for initializing a struct field with an earlier field?

Tags: rust

Example code, does not compile:

```
pub struct S {
    pub a: int,
    pub b: int
}

impl S {
    pub fn new(input: int) -> S {
        S { a: input + 1, b: a }
    }
}
```

The `b: a` bit isn't valid syntax, is there any way to do this in current Rust? [rustc 0.13.0-nightly (eedfc0779 2014-11-25 22:36:59 +0000)]

Obviously I could repeat `input + 1` or use a temporary variable, but I'm curious specifically about using an already-initialized field as input to another field.

Comment: Work-around `let c = input + 1; S { a: c, b: c }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not anything for that, nor is it reasonable to expect that there ever will be; <s>Rust’s ownership semantics would make it of very little value as it could only apply to `Copy` types</s> *well, references too*.

The alternatives are so simple that complicating the language for such a feature is pretty much guaranteed not to happen.

Comment: The most useful form would be allowing earlier fields to appear in the initialisation of later fields (e.g. `S { a: input + 1, b: a.to_string() }`) and this certainly could work with non-`Copy` types.

Comment: True, I had somehow forgotten about references.

Comment: Calling functions/methods with a reference to the earlier field was indeed what I was really interested in, thanks @dbaupp.